# How firebase-invite sends SMS on Android without SEND_SMS in manifest

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I integrated Firebase App Invite in my app as per the doc.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

I would like to know how Firebase sends the SMS without mention of SMS in the manifest. I tested it on my phone, and it did in fact deliver an SMS when I added a contact with only a number. Further the SMS appears in the messaging conversation on the phone, which eliminates the possibility of server-side SMS with SMS binds and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Invites on Android is linked very closely to Play Services, which exists on Android devices in a special APK that has permission to do everything.  Even though the Firebase Invites SDK doesn't require permission to send SMS, it is communicating with Play Services, which does have that permission.  In other words, the SDK is essentially routing the request through Play Services, so your app doesn't need the SMS permission.

Answer (score 0):

When using services/libraries like Firebase you don't need the add any additional permission to the AndroidManifest.xml because these files internally manage the code to add permission when needed by the app.
If you are gating the SMS that you sent to another contact number then is because Firebase doesn't require Permissions to things as it's a product of Google and Android permits Firebase to do so.